# NULL Data in ViewHolder (Simple ListDemo and RecyclerView)

Tags: android, list, view, android-recyclerview

I was trying to make a simple ListViewDemo but dont know what I am missing? Is there any thing missing in the adapter class? In debugging the data is passing to the model class but it ain't showing to the recycler view. TextView in Holder class is always showing **null**

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycleView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    addData();

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myList, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void addData() {
    myList.add(new MyClass("John", "LA"));
    myList.add(new MyClass("Adam", "Paris"));
    myList.add(new MyClass("Hary", "DC"));
    myList.add(new MyClass("Tom", "Cal"));
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<MyClass> myList, Context context) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextName.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
    holder.mTextCity.setText(myList.get(position).getCity());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mTextName;
    TextView mTextCity;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        mTextCity= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCity);
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class MyClass {

String name;
String city;

public MyClass(String name, String city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
}
```

**XML File**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCity"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="City" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error**

```
Unable to locate gmscore in dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes3.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes4.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes5.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /system/lib]]]
                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gmscore from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes3.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes4.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes5.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                          at kgr.b(:com.google.android.gms@11945030:30)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms@11945030:1)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.insertProvider(:com.google.android.gms@11945030:9)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.insertProviderGated(:com.google.android.gms@11945030:7)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@11945030:15)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: could you please provide your `list_items.xml` file and the code for your `MyClass.java`?

Comment: @ReneFerrari done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rv1;
List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
MyAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test();
}

private void test() {
    rv1 = findViewById(R.id.rv1);
    myList.add(new MyClass("John", "LA"));
    myList.add(new MyClass("Adam", "Paris"));
    myList.add(new MyClass("Hary", "DC"));
    myList.add(new MyClass("Tom", "Cal"));
    rv1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myList, this);
    rv1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<MyClass> myList, Context context) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextName.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
    holder.mTextCity.setText(myList.get(position).getCity());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mTextName;
    TextView mTextCity;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        mTextCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCity);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you update your code as my answer above ? i used your code, updated something and it worked fine.